# powershell check directory for files

Tags: file, validation, powershell

I have a folder that should contain 10 files. Each file name will be different (name and extension), however, it will contain a pattern.

eg.

```
SomeThing.FILE0.DAT
SomeThing.FILE1.DAT
SomeThing.FILE2.DAT
 and so on till
SomeThing.FILE9.DAT
```

My script currently does not have any checks. I manually run it ensuring that all files are present.

```
for ($i=0; $i -le 9; $i++)
{
    $FileString = "*FILE"+$i+"*"
    $MyFileName = Get-ChildItem e:\files -name -filter $($FileString)
}
```

However, I need to automate the process, so I want to add checks to make sure that:

```
a. Total of 10 files exist in that folder

$FC = ( Get-ChildItem c:\testing | Measure-Object ).Count;
if($FC -eq 10)
{
    echo "File Count is correct"
}
else
{
    echo "File Count is incorrect"
}

b. Each of the FILEX (X = 0-9) are present
c. Only one instance of each FILEX (X = 0-9) should be present. If multiple instances of FILEX are present, I need to display it on the screen saying that FILEX pattern is repeated multiple times.
```

How can I do these remaining checks? It looked simple, but is more complicated...

Comment: I see you have already provided the answer for the first part of your question.  Have you tried anything thus far for b or c?  If you have, where have you run into issues?

Comment: No. I am unable to get something for the b and c. Any pointers are appreciated. I have started learning powershell a couple of months ago.

Comment: Make *an* attempt at B & C. This site isn't meant for people to write all your code for you.

Comment: @alroc I am new to powershell/ scripting and trying to learn more and more every day. I know how StackExchange (and its likes ExpertsExchange) works. Sometimes, I draw a blank on how to solve a problem and reach out to users here for pointers.

Comment: Try something. Anything. You already figured out part A, so you do have *some* knowledge. Keep plugging away. Write out an approach to the problem on paper, in plain English (or whatever your preferred language may be). **Then** translate it to code. But giving up before you start is not a way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

```
$> if ((compare (ls -name | %{ ([regex]'(?<=.*FILE).*(?=.DAT)').match($_).groups[0].value } | Sort-Object) (0..9 | %{$_.ToString()}) -SyncWindow 0).Length -eq 0) { Write-Host "ok" }
ok
```

---

Uh?

Rephrasing your question we have something like "check that directory contains only `*FILEX.DAT` files, where X should be every possible number between 0 and 9". In powershell it should look something like that:

```
$> if (allNumbersFromFileNames.IsEqualTo(0..9)) { Write-Info "ok" }
```

To get all numbers from filenames from the current directory:

```
$> ls -name | %{ ([regex]'(?<=.*FILE).*(?=.DAT)').match($_).groups[0].value }
0
1
2
3
5
6
7
8
9
4
```

We've constructed regex here with `([regex]'(?<=.*FILE).*(?=.DAT)')` and for every filename in current directory (`ls -name | %{ $_ }`) parse the magic number in it and get a first matched group's value.

Finally we need to have this `string[]` object, sort it and compare with array of strings of numbers. `compare` could be useful here.

I.e.

```
$> if ((compare 0..9 1..4).Length -eq 0) { Write-Host "equals" }
$> if ((compare 0..9 0..9).Length -eq 0) { Write-Host "equals" }
equals
```

Put it all together and you have an answer!

Comment: Thanks. The "something" is going to be different always. So, any way to remove that?

Comment: answer is updated. `'(?<=SomeThing.FILE).*(?=.DAT)'` regex become `'(?<=.*FILE).*(?=.DAT)'`. Also sorting of array of parsed digits is added to comparing arrays correctly.

Comment: Thanks. This breakup helps a lot :) Appreciate your help in writing this out clearly.

Comment: For some reason, I am getting a FALSE. Even when I am trying `if ((compare 0..9 0..9).Length -eq 0) { Write-Host "equals" }` the output does not come. Is it Powershell version dependent? I believe I have V2

Comment: not sure how to test this code in V2, I have V4 (comes with w8)

Answer (score 0):

Since the regex solution did not work for me, i ended you writing a crude logic. So far it works. If anything better is available, please advise.

```
for ($i=0; $i -le 9; $i++)
{
$FileString = "*FILE"+$i+"*"

$ct = (Get-ChildItem "C:\testing" -name -filter $($FileString) | Measure-Object ).Count
if($ct -ne 1)
{
    if($ct -eq 0)
    {
        write-host "FILE"$i "is missing"
    }
    elseif ($ct -gt 1)
    {
        write-host $ct" instances of FILE"$i" found"
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "God help you."
    }
}
}
```